# ASP.NET developer looking to get into SharePoint - 2007 or 2010?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I've been working with ASP.NET for about 5 years now and I'm looking to get into SharePoint development.

Would it make more sense to get up to speed on SP 2007 first or just dive straight into SP 2010?

Seems like learning SP 2007 would give me a better understanding of the "story" and broaden my work opportunities.

What do we think? Is a grasp of SP 2007 a must for any SP developer at this point?

**Thanks**

Thanks for the helpful and encouraging answers. Seems the unanimous recommendation is to skip SP 2007 and dive straight into SP 2010 as the dev tools are much better, so I'll probably do that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077957/how-to-get-started-with-developing-sharepoint-web-parts/4079865#4079865) I think people starting should focus on 2010.  Depending on your work situation, it may limit you in the types of contract jobs you can take, but the development environment is significantly better in 2010.  The only reason to start with 2007 is so you can appreciate how much easier 2010 makes it :)

Comment: I completely agree. The Visual Studio tools in the 2010 world cut the learning curve dramatically. Don't get me wrong in the long run you're going to want to learn what the tools are doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 is a completely new architecture and is fundamentally different in many ways. For example, SharePoint Services Provider is no more and the sandbox has been added.

I started with 2007 because that's where we are at work. I think the version being used in your workplace should dictate your decision (unless you're a consultant).

Comment: I would disagree about being completely new / fundamentally different - there are far more similarities than differences.

Comment: @Ryan, Agree. "Some big changes..." would have been more accurate. +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, starting with SP 2010 would be easier - the support for SP 2010 development comes built in with VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would gain that much from starting with SharePoint 2007. As the others have said, the development environment with 2010 is much friendlier and doesn't require as many 3rd party tools.
More importantly though, the object model is almost the same. While it is true that SharePoint Service Provider is gone, it is not something that you play with a lot when you develop (in my experience anyway). The important objects and concepts (content types, web parts, lists, list items, etc.) are pretty much the same, which is why I don't think there is much of a "story" to get.
Make your life easier and go with 2010.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is a much easier way to start as others have already suggested. From an analogy perspective, there isn't a lot reason today to learn COM+ programming for instance. You can work with .NET and be happy most of the times.

A couple of real good resources that would help you bring up to speed with SharePoint 2010 are listed below...

1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518660.aspx
2. http://technet.microsoft.com/hi-in/sharepoint/ff420396(en-us).aspx